# Джанго создает бесконечные миграции при использовании кастомного ImageField

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно было генерировать путь сохраняемых фото в модели на лету, поэтому я создал кастомное поле ImageField:

```py
class ProductImageField(ImageField):
    def __init__(self, prefix='', upload_to='', **kwargs):
        self.prefix = prefix
        super().__init__(upload_to=self.custom_upload_to,  **kwargs)

    allowed_ext = ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif')

    def custom_upload_to(self, instance, file_name):
        ext = file_name.split('.')[-1].lower()
        if ext in self.allowed_ext:
            dirname = rus_slugify(instance.brand.value)
            salt = random.randint(10000, 99999)
            filename = f'{rus_slugify(instance.model.value)}_{salt}.{ext}'
            return os.path.join(instance.base_upload_dir, self.prefix, dirname, filename)
        else:
            raise Exception('Файл имеет недопустимое расширение:', ext)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if self.prefix:
            kwargs['prefix'] = self.prefix
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

А затем применил его в обычной модели

```py
class ProductPhoto(models.Model):
    big = ProductImageField(prefix='big', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    small = ProductImageField(prefix='small', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, editable=False)
```

Все работает корректно, но Джанго создает одинаковую миграцию каждый раз когда я запускаю `makemigrations`. В миграции изменение полей big и small. Из-за чего это может происходить и как это победить?

Comment: Из-за того, что каждый раз при создании поля задаётся совершенно новый upload_to, потому что `self.custom_upload_to is self.custom_upload_to` всегда False

Comment: Но истинная причина в том, что вы не следовали документации и не создали обязательный метод deconstruct https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction

Comment: Добавьте правильно реализованный deconstruct и всё будет норм

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за наводку, я попробую

Comment: @andreymal добавил `deconstruct` в текст вопроса, что-то не помогло :(

Comment: @andreymal О, кажется, я решил проблему, сбросив значение поля `upload_to` в 'deconstruct'. Просто вот так: `kwargs['upload_to'] = ' '`